# Error during splunk module installation

Tags: python, splunk

I get error during splunk's python module installation.

```
-ltm:splunk-sdk-python root# easy_install splunklib.binding
Searching for splunklib.binding
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/splunklib.binding/
Couldn't find index page for 'splunklib.binding' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for splunklib.binding
error: Could not find suitable distribution for     Requirement.parse('splunklib.binding')

-ltm:splunk-sdk-python root# pwd
/var/root/splunk-sdk-python
```

can somebody please help to get this module installed.

Comment: try `easy_install splunk-sdk` source: https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-python#installing-the-sdk

Comment: easy_install splunk-sdk worked successfully. I am looking for this splunklib.binding

Comment: `splunk-sdk` provides you with `spluklib.binding`, `binding` is a module in `splunklib`, try `import splunklib.binding as binding` this will give you methods in binding like `binding.connect()` see this example: https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-python/blob/ceba6a0da65f1b8404d461616c3d7b944946033d/examples/abc/b.py

Comment: Great...thanks much !